# Adding active class to menu in asp.net core?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

it's my menu

```html
<nav class="moduletable navigation hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("GameVideos", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "GameVideos")">videogame</a></li>                                
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("SystemRequirements", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SystemRequirements")">systemReq</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("Games", "UpcommingGames")"><a href="@Url.Action("UpcommingGames", "Games")">upcomming game</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and this method check menu active

```
 public static string IsActive(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var returnActive = (controller == routeController && action == routeAction);

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
```

When I select menu it is working but when I click on one game and see details active class is removed, this code just worked for index view and but not working for details menu

Comment: game is a controller action or rendered in view or you are called any ajax function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you must just change isactive method like this :

```
public static string IsActive(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var returnActive = (controller == routeController && (action == routeAction || routeAction == "Details"));

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Work in .Core 2.2 / 3.x

1- In make this way in Layout.cshtml, last lines:

```
@if (ViewData["Active"] != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("@ViewData["Active"]").classList.add("active")</script>
}
```

2- In _MenuPartial or another *.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Super Administração";
    ViewData["Active"] = "Home";
}
```

3- Set the ID according to the ViewData passed in the header

```
<a id="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Super" class="nav-link">
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to try this C# code

```
public static string IsActive(this IHtmlHelper html, string controller = null, string action = null, string cssClass = null)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
            cssClass = "active";

        string currentAction = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        string currentController = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controller))
            controller = currentController;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
            action = currentAction;

        return controller.ToLower().Split(',').Contains(currentController.ToLower()) && action.ToLower().Split(',').Contains(currentAction.ToLower()) ?
            cssClass : String.Empty;
    }
```

In cshtml, you need to change

```
    <nav class="moduletable navigation hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("GameVideos", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "GameVideos")">videogame</a></li>                                
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("SystemRequirements", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SystemRequirements")">systemReq</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("Games", "UpcommingGames,Details”)”><a href="@Url.Action("UpcommingGames”, "Games")">upcomming game</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```